# Rails - Manipulate has_many with join model through single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following three models:

```
class Site < AR::Base
  has_many :installed_templates, :as => :installed_templateable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :installed_templates, :allow_destroy => true, :update_only => true, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t[:template_id].nil? }
 end

class Template < AR::Base
  has_many :installed_templates, :inverse_of => :template
end

class InstalledTemplate < AR::Base
  belongs_to :template, :inverse_of => :installed_template
  belongs_to :installed_templateable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The business logic is that several `Templates` exist when I create a `Site` and I can associate as many as I'd like by creating an `InstalledTemplate` for each. A `Site` can only have unique `Templates` - I can't associate the same `Template` twice to a single `Site`.

I have the following on the form for `Site`:

```
<% Template.all.each_with_index do |template| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "site[installed_templates_attributes][][id]", Hash[@site.installed_templates.map { |i| [i.template_id, i.id] }][template.id] %>
  <%= check_box_tag "site[installed_templates_attributes][]]template_id]", template.id, (@site.installed_templates.map(&:template_id).include?(template.id) %>
  <%= label_tag "template_#{template.id}", template.name %>
<% end %>
```

The above is the only thing that seems to work after lots of experimentation. I wasn't able to achieve this at all using the `form_for` and `fields_for` helpers.

It seems like a pretty straight forward relationship and I'm afraid I'm missing something. Anyone have advice on how to accomplish the above in a cleaner fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do two different things here.

1. Select a list of Templates for which you want to create Installed Template joins to the Site.
2. From each selected Template create an instance of an Installed Template which links to the Site.

I think I would handle this through an accessor on the model.

On the Site Model (assuming standard rails naming conventions)

```
attr_accessor :template_ids

def template_ids
  installed_templates.collect{|i_t| i_t.template.id}
end

def template_ids=(ids, *args)
  ids.each{|i| i.installed_template.build(:site_id => self.id, :template_id => i) }
end
```

Then the form becomes pretty simple

```
<% form_for @site do |f| %>
  <% f.collection_select :template_ids, Template.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
<% form_for @site do |f| %>

  <%f.fields_for :installed_templates do |af|%>

    <%= af.text_field :name %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is a join model necessary here?

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
end
```

In the form, easiest if using simple_form:

```
<%= form.input :template_ids, :as => :radio_buttons, :collection => Template.order(:name), :label => 'Templates installed:' %>
```

If the join model is necessary, then I would have a dropdown or list of templates I could add, each with a button that submits the form and adds that template. Then I'd use the update_only nested attributes form to display the currently installed templates with their settings.

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessor :install_template_id
  before_validation :check_for_newly_installed_template
  def check_for_newly_installed_template
    if install_template_id.present?
      template = Template.find install_template_id
      if template.present? and not templates.include?(template)
        self.templates << template
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That works kind of like Drupal, where you have to enable the theme before you can edit its settings or select it as the current theme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The join model is necessary. Imagine if i change the `Template` content for a specific site, I wouldn't want that change reflected on the `Template` itself but only on the `InstalledTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm curious to see if you can accomplish it in a cleaner fashion on a single form though.